# How do I write an "or" logical operator on Prometheus filter

Tags: prometheus, promql

In prometheus query, we can implement 'and' in filter condition by separating with , eg
{job=~"abc", name=~"def"}

how to write the similar query if I want an or condition like below - 
{job=~"abc" or name=~"def}

Answer (score 3):

Use the following PromQL:

```
{job=~"abc"} or {name=~"def}
```

Answer (score 2):

Additional information for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75323242/274937):

If you need locating time series, which contain multiple distinct values for the same label, then use regexp [label matcher](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors) with the needed values delimited by `|`. For example, the following query selects time series, which contain one of (`foo`, `bar` or `baz`) values for the label `label_name`:

```
{label_name=~"foo|bar|baz"}
```

This query works faster than the following one:

```
{label_name="foo"} or {label_name="bar"} or {label_name="baz"}
```